# Find longest non-breaking common elements in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have this list which contain only Ws and Ss:

```
ls = ['W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'S']
```

What I want to do is to extract the longest nonbreaking "S" in that list?
and return the index of that Ss, returning:

```
['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S']
```

and

```
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @thefourtheye: the last list is the *index* of `ls` of longest Ss.

Comment: Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> val = max((list(g) for k, g in
                   groupby(enumerate(ls), itemgetter(1)) if k == 'S'), key=len)
>>> indices, items = zip(*val)
>>> indices
(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
>>> items
('S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S')
```

Comment: You need to add something to pick out `S` in particular, but yeah, I was writing up a `groupby` sol'n too. :-)

Comment: @DSM Thanks! Completely missed that requirement.

Comment: With you elegant condition, how can I modify to include cases where none of "S" occurs in the list?

Comment: @pdubois Add `k != "S"`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Can you be specific? let's say `ls=["W", "W", "W"]` currently it returns `max() arg is an empty sequence` How can I make it to return `indices = [] and items = []`

Comment: @pdubois I see what you meant. In Python 3.4+ it is possible to specify a default value to `max` in case the iterable passed to it is empty. In other versions you can simply add an `if` condition like: `indices = [],items=[];if 'S' in ls: groupby...`

Answer (score 3):

Same solution as Ashwini Chaudhary's minus the elegance,

```
from itertools import groupby

index, result, m_index = 0, [], 0

# Group based on the elements of the list
for item, grp in groupby(ls):
    # Get the grouped items as a list
    grp = list(grp)
    # Filter out `M`s and check if this is the biggest run of `S`s ever seen
    if item == "S" and len(grp) > len(result):
        result, m_index = grp, index
    # Increment the index to keep track of the list covered
    index += len(grp)

print(result, list(range(m_index, m_index + len(result))))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> max((x.group(), x.span()) for x in re.finditer("S+", "".join(ls)))
('SSSSSSSSSSS', (6, 17))

>>> range(6, 17)
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Answer (score -1):

package com.algo.sort;

public class LargestCont{

```
static int g[]={1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};


public static void main(String f[]){
    manage(g);
}


public static void manage(int[] j){
    int max=1; int val=-1; int count=0; int ans=0;
    for(int i=0;i<j.length;i++){
        if(j[i]!=val){
            if(max>count){
                ans=val;
                count=max;
                System.out.println(ans+"...."+count);                   
            }
        val=j[i]; max=1;}else{
            max++;
        }                   
    }

    System.out.println(ans);

}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

```
ls = ['W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'S']
for x,y in enumerate(ls):
    print (x,str(y).split("W"))
```

I found this one.

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce what the OP is after.